# How to ignore my development project for installing a package with pip

Tags: python, pip

I uploaded my package to `testpypi`, and installed it via:

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ myporj==0.1.6
```

However it refuse to install it by saying:

```
Requirement already satisfied: myproj==0.1.6 in ./projs/myproj (0.1.6)
```

I guess I may add the project in editable mode:

```
pip install --editable .
```

However, I know want to disable it. I tried:

```
python setup.py develop --uninstall
```

But it has no effect.

Comment: did you try to uninstall it using `pip uninstall myproj` and then install it using `pip install myproj --no-cache` ?

Answer (score 2):

It may be worth creating a separate env (Virtual Environments) for the installation.

Here are some articles on this subject:

1. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html
2. https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#creating-a-virtual-environment

Or does it need to be installed in the same place?

You can try to find your package `pip search myporj` or `pip list` for show all packages.

And uninstall it later `pip uninstall myporj` (it may require the right of `sudo` in linux) then install again.
Maybe you may need `--no-cache-dir` option to ignore the cache during installation. Here is more details: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#caching